# Second order no Linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving a few problems, I had big troubles with these two equations:

1. $y^2\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left( \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right)^3 = 0$.
2. $y\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left( \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 + 4y^2 = 0$

I was thinking doing the substitution $z = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$, but I think it's wrong. Any clues?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: for 1) y(x)=const. is one solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, try first $y = e^u$ and then $z = u'$.

EDIT: This also works for #2.

Comment: You mean $u' = \dfrac{du}{dx}$, right???

Comment: Yes, that's right.